# Class 'App\Models\AdListing' not found in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have table whose name is ad_listings, I have created model named as AdListing but when i try to use it in controller i get

> Class 'App\Models\AdListing' not found.

```
$Data = AdListing::where('id',$Id)->get();
```

Comment: maybe it's not in the right positions, or its filename is wrong...

Comment: Do you use classes in your controller? Did you declare the correct namespace in your model? I think you need to provide more details because it is difficult for people to help you without enough information.

Comment: please check your model class file, adlisting model is available on models folder?

Answer (score 0):

**Add in your controller.**

```
use App\AdListing;
```

Comment: if its help for you so mark as verified this answer. @user3653474